# Use proof by contradiction to prove that if $a$ and $b$ are odd integers, then $4 \nmid (a^2+b^2)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, alternative-proof

I have been working through the following proof:

Use proof by contradiction to prove that if $a$ and $b$ are odd integers, then $4 \nmid (a^2+b^2)$.

Below, I have included screenshots of the solutions manual to my text book. I am unclear about what happens between steps 3 and 4 (below).

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Would someone be able to help me clarify what is happening between steps 3 and 4? I don't fully understand why we are moving the $4x$ over to the right hand side of the equation (I checked to see if $4x$ was replacing something, but that doesn't seem to be the case). Furthermore, I do not understand why "$4(\text{integer})+2$" concludes that "$2 \mid 4$". Since the proof shows that the $4x$ has been moved over, what is implied by the left-hand side of the equation? I fully understand the proof up to that point. Additionally, if someone has an alternative suggestion for how to prove this (via contradiction), I would appreciate it.

Comment: It should be that $4 = 4x- 4y^2 -4z^2 -4y-4z + 2$, then you can see that $4 = 4a + 2$, this implies that $4|2$.

Comment: Since 4 divides (a^2 +b^2), (a^2 +b^2)/4 = x where x is an integer, so (a^2 +b^2) = 4*x
If a is odd, then a = 2*y + 1 for some integer y (doesn't really matter what y is); similarly b = 2*z -1. the rest of the step is just expanding the epression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clarification of this proof:**

I think a 4 is missing before the first is-sign. Then we would get $$4 = 4x-4y^2-4y-4z^2-4z+2$$

Which is consistent with 
$4x = 4y^2+4y+4z^2+4-2$.

Then the equation is written as $$4 = 4 \times \mathrm{int}+2$$

$$4 = 2 \times 2 \times\mathrm{int}+2$$

$$4 = 2 \times (2 \times\mathrm{int}+1)$$

$$4 = 2 \times a$$

Here we have that $a$ is odd, so $\gcd(4,a)=1$. Hence we must have $4 \mid 2$, contradiction.

---

**Another way:**

Odd numbers are $x \equiv 1,3 \mod 4$

If $x \equiv 1 \mod 4$ then $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

If $x \equiv 3 \mod 4$ then $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Thus odd squares are $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$. Thus the sum of two odd squares is 2 mod 4.

Comment: So, there is likely a distribution/rearrangement that is happening to get to where $4=2a$?

Comment: @mia.avery I don't understand your last question.

Comment: Sorry. I suppose I am inquiring about rearranging $4\times \text{int} +2$ into $4=2\times a$. This was not obvious to me, and it seems as though it was just a rearranging of terms to get back to showing that $a$ was odd... correct? (hope that made sense).

Comment: I have already split that step out in four steps, and there you can also see that $a$ is odd. Please look carefully to my answer.

Comment: I see that. I was just trying to verify that there was an expansion that needed to occur to complete the proof. That is all.

Comment: Yes, you need to write $4\times \mathrm{int}+2 = 2 \times a$ to show that $a$ is odd. Showing that $a$ is odd is an essential part of the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That ending is where I was tripped up, so I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an alternate proof, if you are interested:

Any odd number is of the form $4k+1$ or $4k+3$. If you square these, you get $16k^2+4k+1=4(4k^2+k)+1$ or $16k^2+24k+9=4(4k^2+6+2)+1$.

The point is any odd number squared is of the form $4x+1$, where $x$ is an integer. Thus the sum of two odd numbers squared is of the form $4x+1+4y+1=4(x+y)+2$. It follows that this is not divisibly by 4.

Comment: As it will often turn out useful (but not needed for this problem) one might remark that we even have that odd squares are of the form $8x+1$ with $x$ an integer.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the suggested proof alternative, and it is helpful to see that sum of two odd numbers squared (and their general form).